# intermittent authentication failure sending SMTP with applemail

Tags: mac-osx, sendmail

I have a client that has issues authenticating sent mail using applemail.

When I check the logs I frequently see things of the nature below. IP's changed to xxx and isp anonymized

```
Jun 19 11:07:38 mail sm-mta[30801]: STARTTLS=server, relay=client.isp.net [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx], version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=NOT, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Jun 19 11:07:39 mail sm-mta[30801]: t5JB7WWC030801: client.isp.net [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MSP-v4
Jun 19 11:07:46 mail sm-mta[30804]: STARTTLS=server, relay=client.isp.net [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx], version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=NOT, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Jun 19 11:07:47 mail sm-mta[30804]: t5JB7ihe030804: client.isp.net [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MSP-v4
Jun 19 11:08:00 mail sm-mta[30805]: STARTTLS=server, relay=client.isp.net [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx], version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=NOT, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Jun 19 11:08:03 mail sm-mta[30805]: t5JB7qug030805: client.isp.net [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MSP-v4
Jun 19 11:08:10 mail sm-mta[30806]: STARTTLS=server, relay=client.isp.net [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx], version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=NOT, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Jun 19 11:08:10 mail sm-mta[30806]: AUTH=server, relay=client.isp.net [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx], authid=validclientusername, mech=PLAIN, bits=0
```

This sequence of events is OK since the mail sent in the end, but frequently there are so many `did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN` errors before applemail authenticates that sendmail applys a failed connection rate limit and the client complains.

Is there some bizarre setting that is causing applemail to do this, or do I need to increase the allowed connection attempts?

I am reluctant to do this since it increases other possible security issues. I am using Sendmail 8.14.4
All other devices that connect, Iphones, android phones, Windows do so without problems.

Thank you for any suggestions getting to the root of this, or how I can advise the client to solve it.

Comment: Check existence of DNS records for IP addresses of failing connections ("reverse DNS" - closed loop of `PTR` and `A` records).   Sendmail checks reverse DNS when accepting incoming connections - it MAY create long waits/delays. Typical DNS query timeout is 75s - it may be too much for some clients.

Comment: Hardly, these attempts are space by 6 seconds.  I tried reducing the greeting pause, and now hese attempts are spaced by 1 second